# Rhyming riddle: Endless hunger / Boundless power

Tags: riddle

A rhyming riddle I composed:

> Endless hunger,
> Boundless power.
> The dead ember
> Of the hottest fire.
> Growing stronger
> With every flare.
> Pulls with might,
> The crushing night.
> Nothing escapes
> Its terrible grip.
> It can galaxies
> Swallow and rip.
> What is it?

I paid more attention to the rhymes and structure than to the difficulty of the problem, so it's pretty easy.

What is the answer?

Comment: rot13 Gur boivbhf nafjre vf "Oynpx Ubyr". Ohg vg pnaabg or gung fgenvtug sbejneq, evtug?

Comment: @DrD the OP said "it is a pretty easy one." so I think you r right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guess.

> black hole

Endless hunger,
Boundless power.

> nothing can escape the boundless hunger of a black hole, and it's "never full"

The dead ember
Of the hottest fire.

> stellar black holes form when a massive star collapses in upon itself.

Growing stronger
With every flare.

> with every flare pulled in, the black hole increases in mass, thus growing stronger.

Pulls with might,
The crushing night.

> black holes pull with the crushing might of gravity, but they are black as night

Nothing escapes
Its terrible grip.

> nothing escapes a black hole, even light

It can galaxies
Swallow and rip.

> black holes are known to rip away at stars

What is it?